# Discord avatar embed

Tags: javascript, discord

For some reason if I try to set the image of an avatar in the embed it just shows up blank in the embed. It should be grabbing the url considering that is what the function does so I am lost. Keep in mind I am also new to this so not sure if this is an easy fix or not. I have tried lots of things and im just lost at this point so just asking here.

```
if(command==="av") {
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
const avatarembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0x333333)
    .setAuthor(user.username)
    .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL);
message.channel.send(avatarembed);
}
```